# Rails running duplicate queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

My app retrieves a set of tags per post, but for some reason it is running duplicate queries:

```
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts`  WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1                      
Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `post_tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `post_tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `post_tags`.`post_id` = 107
Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `post_tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `post_tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `post_tags`.`post_id` = 107  ORDER BY post_tags.created_at
Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `post_tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `post_tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `post_tags`.`post_id` = 106
Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `post_tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `post_tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `post_tags`.`post_id` = 106  ORDER BY post_tags.created_at
Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `post_tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `post_tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `post_tags`.`post_id` = 105
Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `post_tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `post_tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `post_tags`.`post_id` = 105  ORDER BY post_tags.created_at
```

to keep it simple my code in the view page:

```
@posts.each do |post| 
    # code/html to print out post here
    print_tags(post.tags.order('created_at desc'))
end
```

and here is my code for print_tags in PostsHelper:

```
def print_tags(tags)

    returnStr = ""
    tags.each do |tag| 
        returnStr += "<span class='tags'><a href='/users/#{@user.id}/tags/#{tag.tag_name.gsub(' ', '-')}'>#{tag.tag_name}</a></span>" 
    end

    returnStr
end
```

What I don't understand is why it runs a query first without the order_by, and then runs the query with it. Performance isn't bad *yet*, but if it really is running two queries for each post, then that could get ugly pretty fast.

Comment: I think it will be useful if you provide the method "print_tags".
I think a better practice would be to load the posts as a chunk though. Instead of @posts.each do |post| ... end, probably a better way would be @posts.include(:tags).order('tags.created_at desc') or something like that. Probably would result in only 1 database query instead of 1 query every post. *untested code* http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: Are you using post.tags elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah, it seems I was using post.tags.length somewhere too. Using eager loading seemed to fix the problem though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try eager loading your tags associations:

```
@posts.includes(:tags).each do |post| 
  # do something with `post.tags`
end
```

See [Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)